# How to make two y-axis graph appear together using my own phpMyadmin database

Tags: php, mysql

i'm relatively new to the website and seeking help for the current project i'm doing which is to show two line graphs appear on the y-axis with a constant x-axis. My code looks something like this for the php:

```
        <?php

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            $lala = 'gender_male';
            $lele = 'gender_female';
            $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","imnoob","csv_db");

            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to DataBase: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }else
            {
                $data_points = array();
                $data_points1 = array();
                $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM centurysq2012");

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {        
                    $point = array("x" => $row['weekid'] , "y" => $row[$lala]);
                    $point1 = array("x" => $row['weekid'], "y" => $row[$lele]);
                    array_push($data_points, $point);     
                    array_push($data_points1, $point1);   
                }

                echo json_encode($data_points, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
                echo json_encode($data_points1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
            }
            mysqli_close($con);

            ?>
```

which will be put into my html file codes which is something like this:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="canvasjs.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).onload(function () {


                $.getJSON("doubleline.php", function (point, point1) {
                    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                        theme: "theme2",
                        title: {
                            text: "Footfall by Gender"
                        },
                        animationEnabled: true,
                        axisX: {
                            valueFormatString: ""
                            //intervalType: "month"
                        },
                        toolTip: {
                            shared: true
                        },
                        axisY: {
                            gridColor: "Silver",
                            tickColor: "silver"
                        },
                        data: [
                            {
                                type: "line",
                                showInLegend: true,
                                lineThickness: 2,
                                name: "Male",
                                markerType: "square",
                                color: "#F08080",
                                dataPoints: point
                            },
                            {
                                type: "line",
                                showInLegend: true,
                                name: "Female",
                                color: "#20B2AA",
                                lineThickness: 2,
                                dataPoints: point1
                            }],
                        legend: {
                            cursor: "pointer",
                            itemclick: function (e) {
                                if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                                    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                                } else {
                                    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                                }
                                chart.render();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    chart.render();

                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="chartContainer" style="width:400px; height:100%;"></div>

    </body>
</html>



Sorry for my codes being messy or the question being a lousy one as i'm still currently a student. Thank you for all your help in advance!
```

Answer (score 0):

$.getJson method will only return your PHP output result as a variable, you can't assign it into point1, point2. So for your PHP coding, you probably need to do the below amendments:

$result = array($data_points,$data_points1);
echo json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

instead of echo json_encode($data_points, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
           echo json_encode($data_points1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

In order to show two lines you will need to make 2 sets of data inside your data-> for eg: data:[{SET1}, {SET2}], you may refer the HTML codes below, this will show you 2 lines on your chart:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {

      title:{
      text: "Earthquakes - per month"
      },
      axisX: {
        valueFormatString: "MMM",
        interval:1,
        intervalType: "month"
      },
      axisY:{
        includeZero: false

      },
      data: [
      {
        type: "line",

        dataPoints: [
        { x: new Date(2012, 00, 1), y: 450 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 414},
          { x: new Date(2012, 02, 1), y: 520, indexLabel: "highest",markerColor: "red", markerType: "triangle"},
        { x: new Date(2012, 03, 1), y: 460 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 04, 1), y: 450 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 05, 1), y: 500 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 06, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 07, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 08, 1), y: 410 , indexLabel: "lowest",markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey", markerType: "cross"},
        { x: new Date(2012, 09, 1), y: 500 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 10, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 11, 1), y: 510 }
        ]
      },
        
      {
        type: "line",

        dataPoints: [
        { x: new Date(2012, 00, 1), y: 420 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 404},
          { x: new Date(2012, 02, 1), y: 520, indexLabel: "highest",markerColor: "red", markerType: "triangle"},
        { x: new Date(2012, 03, 1), y: 400 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 04, 1), y: 400 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 05, 1), y: 500 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 06, 1), y: 450 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 07, 1), y: 490 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 08, 1), y: 415 , indexLabel: "lowest",markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey", markerType: "cross"},
        { x: new Date(2012, 09, 1), y: 490 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 10, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 11, 1), y: 510 }
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
  }
  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

your chart will look like this: 
[2 lines chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGV53.png)

for your case, maybe something like this:

```js
$(document).onload(function () {


                $.getJSON("doubleline.php", function (result) {
                  var point1 = result[0];
                  var point2 = result[1];
                    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                        theme: "theme2",
                        title: {
                            text: "Footfall by Gender"
                        },
                        animationEnabled: true,
                        axisX: {
                            valueFormatString: ""
                            //intervalType: "month"
                        },
                        toolTip: {
                            shared: true
                        },
                        axisY: {
                            gridColor: "Silver",
                            tickColor: "silver"
                        },
                        data: [
                            {
                                type: "line",
                                showInLegend: true,
                                lineThickness: 2,
                                name: "Male",
                                markerType: "square",
                                color: "#F08080",
                                dataPoints: point
                            },
                            {
                                type: "line",
                                showInLegend: true,
                                name: "Female",
                                color: "#20B2AA",
                                lineThickness: 2,
                                dataPoints: point1
                            }],
                        legend: {
                            cursor: "pointer",
                            itemclick: function (e) {
                                if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                                    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                                } else {
                                    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                                }
                                chart.render();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    chart.render();

                });

            });
```